# Webkit CSS animation-fill-mode appears to override CSS media queries

Tags: css, webkit, css-animations, css-transforms

I have some elements that have both CSS transforms and animations.  It seems that by using `animation-fill-mode` (which maintains the final animation), **no** subsequent style changes (from media queries) will take place.

I created [an example codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ulawg).

Load the page >1000px wide, then after load drag it to less than 1000px wide.  Firefox applies the CSS transform (`rotate(20deg)`), but Webkit (Safari and Chrome) does not.  I understand that `animation-fill-mode` maintains the final animation styles, but it seems to be overriding all future media query style changes

How do I get Webkit to display the attributes on window size change less than 1000px wide?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma after `opacity: .5` in the `@media` query

You should also put the default, non-prefixed `animation-fill-mode` and animations ***after*** the prefixed versions

```
-moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```